# Does the amount owed listed in my account on irs.gov include both federal and state taxes owed?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, state-income-tax

I don't see any kind of indication of whether the amount owed listed in my account on irs.gov includes both federal and state or just federal.

Comment: Decrease your allowances so you get a refund at the end of the year instead of owing. Tax season is a MUCH nicer experience when IRS owes  you money. There aren't even penalties for filing late!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nope, the IRS just deals with federal. You'll have to work with your state's department/office of revenue to settle up with them.